# how to show a wpf window without having to create another instance

Tags: c#, wpf, static

(I'm trying to create my own custom MSGBOX from wpf...)
How do I show another WPF Window without having this kind of code

```
WpfWindow w = new WpfWindow();
w.SetBox("hellow world");
w.ShowDialog();
```

however i kind of found a way to lessen the CODE but i still need to create another instance (which is a waste of resources)

```
new WpfWindow().ShowBox("hellow world");
```

the ShowBox(string msg) Method:

```
public bool? ShowBox()
{
    SetBox(msg);
    return w.ShowDialog();
}
```

I want to get rid of that "*new*" code snippet (if that's what you call it)

so...in conclusion...I wanted to know how to make a ***Static*** WPF Window...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply wrap your code in a static method in your class:

```
class WpfWindow {

  public static bool? Show(String message) {
    var window = new WpfWindow();
    window.SetBox(message);
    return window.ShowDialog();
  }

}
```

You then call it like this:

```
var result = WpfWindow.Show("Hello world");
```

You may object to the fact that a new instance of the window is created on each call but I don't think you can avoid that. You are using `ShowDialog` to show a modal dialog and for this dialog to return control to your code it has to be closed. A closed window cannot be reopened and you have to create a new instance each time. It shouldn't be a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a singleton pattern?

```
private static WpfWindow _instance;
public static WpfWindow Instance
{
    get
    {
       if(_instance == null) _instance = new WpfWindow();
       return _instance;
     }
}
```

caller:

```
WpfWindow.Instance.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: The second call to `ShowDialog` will fail with an `InvalidOperationException`. You cannot reopen a closed window and `ShowDialog` will not return before the window is closed.

Comment: I had no idea of the functional limitation. The question sounded like an out-of-the-book situation for a singleton. Thanks for the heads up though :)